# Python Django getattr(): attribute name must be string

Tags: python, django

I am using python, Django and get the following error:

```
getattr(): attribute name must be string

location: val = getattr(obj, field)

        if field in headers:
            if not isinstance(field, str):
                val = getattr(obj, field)
            else:
                val = getattr(obj, field.LastName)

            if callable(val):
                val = val()
            if type(val) == unicode:
                val = val.encode("utf-8")
            row.append(val)
```

I have tried many variation of code but all failed.

Comment: The error message is telling you the attribute name must be a string, and you are specifically calling `getattr(obj, field)` after testing that `field` is *not* a string.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: @BrenBarn field is a string, I have also used val = getattr(obj, "LastName") but that's also not working. As I've just started learning python I'm a naive in it. I could also upload my entire function if that doesn't flaws stackoverflow's policy...

Answer (score 5):

You can confirm the object type of `field` by using `print(type(field))`. It will likely not be a string considering the error.

Looking at your code, it looks like `field` will be an object with *attributes* that are strings, such as `LastName`. The line

`val = getattr(obj, field)`

would probably be better off reading

`val = getattr(obj, field.someattribute)`

If `field.someattribute` is not a string, you can cast it to string using 
`str(field.someattribute)`

For a grand total of `val = getattr(obj, str(field.someattribute))`

Answer (score 5):

May be you are missing the attribute name.

I was getting the same error for this

```
price = models.DecimalField(15, 2,)
```

but when I modified the code like below error was resolved.

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,)
```