# not able to start the start the server djano

Tags: django, django-views

updated version

```
 # Create your models here.
    class PlacedOrder(models.Model):
        restraunt = models.ForeignKey(Restraunts, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        order_time = models.TimeField(
            auto_now_add=True)
        estimated_delivery_time = models.TimeField()
        actual_delivery_time = models.TimeField()
        food_ready_time = models.TimeField()
        total_price = models.DecimalField(9, 2)
```

I am getting this error for no reason, not knowing where the problem lies, it's not allowing me to run migrations as well, I have posted by trace below, need help with this

```
  "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
            self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
            autoreload.raise_last_exception()
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 87, in raise_last_exception
            raise _exception[1]
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
            autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 64, in wrapper
            fn(*args, **kwargs)
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
            apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
            app_config.import_models()
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 301, in import_models
            self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
          File "C:\Users\atif\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\food_deliveryapp\orders\models.py", line 9, in <module>
            class PlacedOrder(models.Model):
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 161, in __new__
            new_class.add_to_class(obj_name, obj)
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 326, in add_to_class
            value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
          File "C:\Users\atif\PycharmProjects\my_proj_basic\virtual-env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 788, in contribute_to_class
            if not getattr(cls, self.attname, None):
        TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

Comment: Please share the relevant source code.

Comment: i have only defined models and they seem to be having no errors, i  don't know what's wrong , i have defined no views yet , just made 3 apps and defines models in them only

Comment: Looking at trace seems some issue with the model that you created i.e. `PlacedOrder `. Also you are not able to run the migrations. Then how you validated that models seems to have no error...??

Comment: kindly check i have updated it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Django getattr(): attribute name must be string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633821/python-django-getattr-attribute-name-must-be-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are missing the attribute name.

```
price = models.DecimalField(15, 2,)
```

Try This:

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2,)
```